# Converting NodeJs / express HTTP server to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, node-modules

So I have a basic NodeJS server which I am trying to convert from HTTP to HTTPS.

Here is the old code (HTTP) which works:

```js
const express = require('express');
const port = 80;

const app = express();

app.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on ' + port));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({'limit':'2mb'}));
```

I've been looking up how to convert this to HTTPS. I have tried many attempts but I just cant seem to get this working. Below is my current state of code.

New code (HTTPS) does not work:

```js
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 443;

var key = fs.readFileSync('./private/privkey.pem');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('./private/fullchain.pem');

var options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert
  };

var app = express();

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => console.log('listening on ' + port));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({'limit' : '2mb'}));
```

The port does seem to open and listen but whenever I try to connect via browser, I get the error:

`"<ip> didn’t send any data."`
`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

I have tried omitting the express app from the https server and replacing with

```js
function (req, res) { res.send('hello!') }
```

But this did not make any difference in the error.

I am truly stuck now as I have checked so many forums and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

I am not getting any syntax errors from running index.js

Comment: off topic, but is there any reason why reverse proxy (e.g. nginx ) is not used?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I've never used it before. I am just trying to go from HTTP to HTTPS using the same codebase

Comment: as a long-time nodejs developer, my advise is for you is to go for nginx reverse proxy, which is what majority of nodejs developers are doing. Reverse proxy handles the ssl termination for you, gzipping, caching etc. Unless really required, we don't code the SSL termination on the application.

Comment: If this same structure works for http, then this code should work as long as port 443 is open and as long as your https certificate matches the domain you're trying to run it on.